# Seeding Autocorrect

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autocorrect

I am trying to seed autocorrect (either permanently or for the current scope of an input view). This could be useful if your user could possibly reference a name or something unique that wouldn't be in the standard dictionary.

What is the API that you can use for this?